# Git difftool no outoup

Tags: git, shell

I have a newly created file on local git repository that is not staged.
I want to execute

```
git difftool --dir-diff HEAD
```

or

```
git difftool HEAD path
```

to force to open installed difftool.  Currently git gives me no output.

Is this possible? What arguments/ settings I need to do in order to launch difftool.

I have tried kdiff3 and beyond compare as difftool and git version 1.8.5 if this is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

> What arguments/ settings I need to do in order to launch difftool.

You need to add the following to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[diff]
    tool = kdiff3
```

That would assume that `kdiff3` is in the PATH, otherwise you need to set `difftool.kdiff3.path` as well. Read more about it at the [git-difftool(1) Manual Page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool.html).

Comment: I have difftool configured. git difftool work well for files that are in modified state, only for new created files difftool is not launching.

Comment: If newly created files are in the index (git status shows `A` for them) then you need to diff them with `--cached`.